# Selenium Python mouse hover over TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use an If statement to check if some text is in a variable.
The variable contains some text which has been performed by a mouse hover over.
The scenario is: Hover the mouse over a cell in a report on a webpage.
I have got the text into a variable and I have printed it to the console. I know the text has been captured.

My IF statement is failing.  I get the error:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

My IF statement is:

```
if "DO_NAME" in matchAudit_element:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

My code snippet is:

```
 def mouse_hover_over_match_audit_code_for_matches_filtered_report(self):
    match_audit_element = self.get_element(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="reporting_view_report_dg_main_body"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]//div//span[contains(@title,"Matched from: DO_NAME")]')
    print "match_audit_element ********************************"
    print match_audit_element.text
    print "Mouse Hover Over >>>>>>>>>>"
    self.mouse_hover_over(match_audit_element)
    return self.mouse_hover_over(match_audit_element)

def is_mouse_hover_over_match_audit_code_for_matches_filtered_report(self):
    matchAudit_element = self.mouse_hover_over_match_audit_code_for_matches_filtered_report()
    if "DO_NAME" in matchAudit_element:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The output to the console is:

```
match_audit_element ********************************
DO_NAME[xt ]DO_ADDRESS[B]DO_DOB[]
Mouse Hover Over >>>>>>>>>>
```

What am I doing wrong?  It is something in my IF statement.

Thanks,
Riaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `matchAudit_element` is a `WebElement`. The `in` statement can be used to check the presence of a sub string or the presence of an item in an array. So replacing `matchAudit_element` by `matchAudit_element.text` should fix it :

```
def is_mouse_hover_over_match_audit_code_for_matches_filtered_report(self):
    matchAudit_element = self.mouse_hover_over_match_audit_code_for_matches_filtered_report()
    if "DO_NAME" in matchAudit_element.text:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Moreover, the method `mouse_hover_over` probably doesn't return anything. Try to explicitly return the `match_audit_element`:

```
def mouse_hover_over_match_audit_code_for_matches_filtered_report(self):
    match_audit_element = self.get_element(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="reporting_view_report_dg_main_body"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[4]//div//span[contains(@title,"Matched from: DO_NAME")]')
    print "match_audit_element ********************************"
    print match_audit_element.text
    print "Mouse Hover Over >>>>>>>>>>"
    self.mouse_hover_over(match_audit_element)
    self.mouse_hover_over(match_audit_element)
    return match_audit_element
```

Comment: I get the error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @Riaz Ladhani, the method `mouse_hover_over` probably doesn't return anything. Try to return `match_audit_element`.